# Как вставить изображение в SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

Вот макет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот svg код, который не работает.

```
<svg width="727" height="620" viewBox="0 0 727 620" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<path d="M533.771 0H0V620H727V247.5L533.771 0Z" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
<path d="M533.771 0H0V620H727V247.5L533.771 0Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0" transform="translate(0 -0.134532) scale(0.000927721 0.00108783)"/>
</pattern>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="711" y1="620" x2="363.5" y2="620" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#0B1424"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<image id="image0" width="1080" height="1080" src="https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/kena-keyart-1200x1600-1200x1600-3cc88c815329.png?h=854&resize=1&w=640" />
</defs>
</svg>
```

То есть, нужна возможность вставлять любую картинку. И правый верхний угол должен быть срезан. Подскажите, где моя ошибка.

Comment: Почему [clip-path](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) не использовать?

Comment: @nazarpunk, похоже, что все работает только с квадратными изображениями. А как уголок с одинаковыми катетами при неквадратных изображениях снять? Есть такая возможность?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для такой обрезки можно использовать `clip-path` в сочетании с `calc()`.

Пример обрезки правого верхнего угла (катеты по 60px):

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  background: #cda;
}
img{
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 60px) 0, 100% 60px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKnFL.png" alt=""/>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Подскажите где моя ошибка.

При добавлении изображения с помощью тега `<image>` вместо `src=` нужно использовать `href=`

```html
<svg width="727" height="620" viewBox="0 0 727 620" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<path d="M533.771 0H0V620H727V247.5L533.771 0Z" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
<path d="M533.771 0H0V620H727V247.5L533.771 0Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0" transform="translate(0 -0.134532) scale(0.000927721 0.00108783)"/>
</pattern>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="711" y1="620" x2="363.5" y2="620" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#0B1424"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
<image id="image0" width="1080" height="1080" href="https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/kena-keyart-1200x1600-1200x1600-3cc88c815329.png?h=854&resize=1&w=640" />
</defs>
</svg>
```

- Добавление изображения с помощью `clipPath`
  Для адаптивности `width="75%" height="75%"`

```html
<svg width="75%" height="75%" viewBox="0 0 727 620" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<clipPath id="cp">
<path transform="translate(-100)" d="M533.771 0H0V620H727V247.5L533.771 0Z" />
</clipPath>
</defs>
<image clip-path="url(#cp)"  id="image0" width="100%" height="100%" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lNYF.png" /> 
</svg>
```

- Добавление изображения с помощью mask

```html
<svg  width="75%" viewBox="0 0 727 620" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<mask id="cp">
<path fill="white" transform="translate(-100)" d="M533.771 0H0V620H727V247.5L533.771 0Z" />
</mask>
</defs>
<image mask="url(#cp)"  id="image0" width="100%" height="100%" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lNYF.png" /> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

В ссылке на картинку есть знаки не разрешенные в таге svg - &, <, >

```
<image id="image0" width="1080" height="1080" src="https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/kena-keyart-1200x1600-1200x1600-3cc88c815329.png?h=854&resize=1&w=640" />
```

Если заменить в ссылке & на %26 [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) то всё работает

```
https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/kena-keyart-1200x1600-1200x1600-3cc88c815329.png?h=854%26resize=1%26w=640
```

Финальный svg выглядит так:

```html
<svg width="727" height="620" viewBox="0 0 727 620" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <path d="M533.771 0H0V620H727V247.5L533.771 0Z" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
    <path d="M533.771 0H0V620H727V247.5L533.771 0Z" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
            <use href="#image0" transform="translate(0 -0.134532) scale(0.000927721 0.00108783)"/>
        </pattern>
        <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="711" y1="620" x2="363.5" y2="620" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop stop-color="#0B1424"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <image id="image0" width="1080" height="1080" href="https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/kena-keyart-1200x1600-1200x1600-3cc88c815329.png?h=854%26resize=1%26w=640" />
    </defs>
</svg>
```

*Редакторы кода такие как IntelliJ или замечательный бесплатный редактор VSCode сразу показывают где ошибка

[image: редактор кода]

Comment: Я же в сниппет переделал чтобы было результат видно))) Попытка номер 2)))

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью canvas:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const image = new Image();
image.src = "https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/kena-keyart-1200x1600-1200x1600-3cc88c815329.png?h=854&resize=1&w=640";
image.onload = () => {
    const w = canvas.width = image.width;
    const h = canvas.height = image.height;
    const path = new Path2D(`M ${w*2/3} 0 L ${w} ${w/3} V ${h} H 0 V 0 z`);
    ctx.clip(path);
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы приложение выглядело один к одному, как на заданном макете, было адаптивным и вёрстка не разъезжалась на разных разрешениях у разных гаджетов и не нужно было заниматься ручной подгонкой размеров с помощью `scale()` `translate()` и заполнять пустоты градиентами, предлагаю воспользоваться несложной техникой с помощью векторного редактора, это будет буквально несколько кликов мышкой

1. Загружаете шаблон в векторный редактор и с помощью инструмента - "Рисовать кривые Безье" <kbd>shift+F6</kbd> наносите по контуру изображения узловые точки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Сохраняете файл в формате *.svg
3. Оптимизируете его с помощью [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)
4. Далее, полученный path используете для обрезки изображения с помощью clipPath, mask

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" fill="none" version="1.1" id="svg4" width="75%" height="75%" viewBox="0 0 727 620">
<defs>
<clipPath id="cp">
<path  d="m0 0 535 0 191 246 0 372H0Z" />
</clipPath>
</defs> 
 <image clip-path="url(#cp)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKnFL.png" id="image2" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Саша у тебя в координатах маленький косячёк - мне можно попробовать поправить - подсказать ?

Comment: @Айболит исправляй, если видишь ошибку, у меня всегда есть возможность откатить правку, если буду не согласен

Comment: ты уже исправил